# Passing code behind parameter to Ext.Net control

Tags: c#, ext.net

I have a variable in a code behind control. I want to pass this value to an Ext.Net control in the web control. In my instance I have an ext.multicombo, and I want to pass a value to it's Tooltip.

Code Behind:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
this.MaxFuelFilter = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyVariable"]; 
}
```

Control.aspx

```
<ext:multicombo ID="ddlFlightNumber" runat="server" ClientID="ddlFlightNumber" IndicatorTip="blah blah blah  <%=MyVariable%> blah blah blah"></ext:multicombo>
```

How do I do something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues:

The syntax you're using will not work with ASP.NET Controls. This is an ASP.NET limitation, and not related to Ext.NET.

This is not valid ASP.NET syntax:

```
PropertyName="foo foo <%=MyVariable%>"
```

And, this is not valid ASP.NET syntax:

```
PropertyName="<%=MyVariable%>"
```

To pass a value into the property, you'll need to use the `<%# %>` DataBinding syntax.

Although, this is also not valid ASP.NET syntax:

```
PropertyName="foo foo <%# MyVariable %>"
```

The property must ONLY contain the databind variable/script, example

```
PropertyName="<%# MyVariable%>"
```

AND... you must call .DataBind() on the Control, example

```
this.MyControl1.DataBind();
```

OR, with Ext.NET Controls, you can set the `.AutoDataBind="true"` property and DataBinding will be automatically handled for you, example

```
<ext:TextField runat="server" PropertyName="<%# MyVariable%>" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

The above custom property is auto-serialized into JavaScript and is now available to the client-side instance of that control (and others). You can then call that property from other JavaScript code.

For your scenario, I'd recommend tapping into an `<AfterRender>` Listener of the `<ext:MultiCombo>` to get the property value and set something else. The following sample demonstrates the complete scenario (`myVar`), and also demonstrates another basic technique (`myVar2`) for passing a JavaScript variable into the client-side from the server-side.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagprefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    string myVar;
    string myVar2;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myVar = "Label 1";
        myVar2 = "Label 2";
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:TextField 
            ID="TextField1" 
            runat="server" 
            MyVar="<%# myVar %>"
            AutoDataBind="true" 
            FieldLabel="Testing">
            <Listeners>
                <AfterRender Handler="this.setFieldLabel(this.myVar);" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:TextField>

        <ext:TextField 
            ID="TextField2" 
            runat="server" 
            MyVar="<%# myVar2 %>"
            AutoDataBind="true" 
            FieldLabel="Testing">
            <Listeners>
                <AfterRender Handler="this.setFieldLabel(myVar2);" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:TextField>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myVar2 = "<%= myVar2 %>";
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You should be able to adapt the above to work with your custom Control.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Geoffrey. I'm a little confused. Am I creating a textfield and passing that to the tooltip of the multicombo control?

Comment: You can pass the value using any component you like. If you can provide a simplified code sample demonstrating your scenario, I'm sure we could offer further suggestions. The information you provided is a little thin on details.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `MyVariable` defined?  If it's a `public` or `protected` member of the page's class and is initialized early enough in the page life cycle (`Page_Init` perhaps?  Maybe `Page_Load` but I'd double-check and test it) then this approach should work.

Comment: I'm setting the var in the OnPreRender. The trouble is I can't find the correct syntax to get the value into the ext control.

Comment: @hoakey: Can you update the question to show how `MyVariable` is declared and initialized?